.Net Kestrel issue with custom server certificate
So I am having an interesting issue, I am making a small GRPC service with a simple configuration and a custom certificate I have generated for it.
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ListenAnyIP(7180, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps("certificates/server1.pfx");
    });
});

now, I want it to use the certificate I gave it but if I remove the ASP.NET generated certificate I have an error message when I launch debug in Visual Studio as:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date
now the completely insane part is that if I do not delete the ASP.NET generated certificate everything launches and it is actually using the certificate I provide on the kestrel configuration line!
I can live with it but it drives me crazy, there must be some check there during the launch process that checks if the ASP.NET certificate exists and if not it vomits an error. Yet the service nicely uses my generated certificate.
This seems to be some Visual Studio thing, I am not generally using IDEs exactly for these kind of things but now I practically have to to work with the team and would be very grateful to know why this is happening.
Thank you very much!
Edit 1 - Adding the launchsettings.json
{
  "profiles": {
    "GrpcService1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5110;https://localhost:7180"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  }
}

Note - the launchsettings.json is more or less default, at least I have not edited anything there...

Please show us your launchSettings.json file.

@Dai edited to include the launchsettings.json

The path "certificates/server1.pfx" will be relative to the working-directory of the program (e.g. bin\x64\Release\net8.0) - so the file needs to be at bin\x64\Release\net8.0\certificates\server1.pfx - is this the case?

...also, it's unusual for a .pfx file to contain a private-key without being encrypted (e.g. by using password-protection, or using DPAPI for key-storage) and in-fact, Windows' Certificate management MMC's GUI wizard actually prevents you from exporting a private-key without it being an encrypted - but your UseHttps() call doesn't provide a password: value. May I ask how you created this .pfx file in the first place?

Yes, also at runtime I can see it is correctly using the server1.pfx as I want but only if I do not delete the default ASP.NET certificate.

On my machines, the "default ASP.NET certificate" is in my Windows profile's cert store, it isn't a file on-disk, so I'm unsure exactly what that cert is in your case...

As for encrypting the pfx, yes I can do it but for now I just load my cert and key to it without password, you can see this as a custom developer cert chain where I can distribute the CA to all the clients, and yes this is only used in development the prod version will get a cert generated from our PKI system, but as every large organization somehow PKI is magical and cannot simple give us dev certs. But indeed the final pfx will contain a password

Yes, I delete it from the personal cert store as I want to use my custom chain and don't like things be left behind, since kestrel has the option to load cert from file, I am a little confused about it complaining

Ugh a quick update, it seems to work in a VS 2022 and if .Net 6 is used. But get the issue with .Net 8?

Oh I create the certs with openssl, I run all dev on linux and just kind of hopped on the .net world and windows here. I just create the whole chain with openssl and then import the key and cert to pfx using openssl pkcs12 module, just leave the password empty

the UseHttps() has an overload for a single parameter of a filename with certificate, so should be possible to run it without password

Using openssl with .pfx files is an exercise in pain; I suggest you (temporarily) eliminate that as a troubleshooting step and instead use PowerShell's New-SelfSignedCertificate cmdlet for a new .pfx file and see if that works.

I also note that .pfx files can contain multiple certificates; is that the case? And you're certain your current cert has not expired (and is also after its Not-Before datetime?)

allright, I am very familiar with openssl but not powershell, will have to investigate how to build a little chain! Will give it a try!

...your signing-chain might also be implicated. What I'm saying is that you should try using it with a single, simple, self-signed cert with no unnecessary extras at-first.

The certificate is valid for another year, I have just put together a quick grpc service in python and it works fine

Will try to remove all unnecessary pieces and just pin the certificate in the test client

...how is client-side certificate-pinning going to help when this is a server-side issue?

Sorry for not being clear, instead of letting my client validate the cert against the CA from the chain I will pin this individual server certificate in my client to run the validation just to compare couple of fields, simply returning true in a client from the cert validation handler would not provide any useful information
